# Как удалить файлы-сессии с одинаковыми данными?

Tags: python

В папке есть несколько файлов-сессий. С помощью каждой отдельной сессии я получаю номер телефона (1 сессия - 1 телефон). Имена файлов-сессий уникальные. Если я получаю номер телефона, который уже был ранее получен (дубликат), то такой файл нужно удалить с диска. Как это сделать?

```
listFiles = ['1.session', '2.session', '3.session']
listTel = ['+777', '+555', '+555']

listClear = set(listTel)

if len(listClear) != len(listTel):
     print('Found Dublicat!')
     # Как удалить файл 3.session?
```

Списки заполняются данными перед каждым запуском. Данные могут отличаться от тех, что я привёл в примере. Нужно решение, подходящее для таких случаев.

Comment: `import os; os.remove(path)`

Comment: А как вы определили, что дубликат именно в фале `3.session`? Может нужно другой файл удалять?

Comment: @suit А я думал, что только я этого не понял :)

Comment: А вы не видите, что в списке телефоны одинаковые на этих позициях?

Comment: @Владимир мы-то видим. Но, наверное, предполагается, что содержимое `listFiles` и `listTel` заранее неизвестно? Что если `listTel` окажется равен `['+555', '+555', '+777']`?

Comment: Разумеется. Простите, что не описал задание настолько подробно. Исправил.

Comment: Давайте я попробую сформулировать задачу за вас: нужно оставить только файлы с самым первым (или единственным) появлением номера (`1.session` и `2.session` в примере), а все последующие дубликаты номеров найти и удалить (`3.session` в примере). Я правильно понял?

Comment: Да, верно. Необходимо оставить только файлы с уникальными номерами телефонов.

Comment: Из исходного текста я понял, что оставлять не первые, а последние. Или там ничего нет, кроме номера?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Т.е. мы обрабатываем файлы сессий, добываем оттуда телефон и, если ранее такого телефона не было, то сохраняем, если уже был, то файл сессии удаляем? Если я правильно понял, то это будет примерно так:

```
def get_tel_from_file(session):
    #здесь идет получение номера из сессии
    return tel_number

list_files = ['1.session', '2.session', '3.session']
unic_list_tel = []

for session_file in list_files:
    tel = get_tel_from_file(session_file)
    if tel in unic_list_tel:
        os.remove(session_file)
    else:
        unic_list_tel.append(tel)
```

P.S. в питоне принято именовать переменные и функции в нижнем регистре со знаками подчеркивания, а не lowerCamelCase, как в Java. Для именования классов используют CamelCase.

Comment: Благодарю. То, что нужно.

Comment: список к квадратичному алгоритму ведёт. Можно линейный алгоритм получить: `tel_numbers = set()`, `tel_numbers.add(tel)`

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
listFiles = ['1.session', '2.session', '3.session']
listTel = ['+777', '+555', '+555']

d = dict(zip(listFiles, listTel))

for key, value in d.items():
        if d.values().count(value) > 1:
                os.remove(key)
                del(d[key])
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'count'

Comment: @Олег данный код же удалит оба файла `2.session` и `3.session`?

Comment: Теперь удалит только один. И да, это решение для питона 2 версии

Comment: Для 3й надо изменить "for key, value in d.items():" на "for key, value in set(d.items()):", а "if d.values().count(value) > 1:" на "if list(d.values()).count(value) > 1:"